# How to synchronize Play (start/stop) between Juno-Gi and Drumbrute?

Tags: midi

Is there a way to synchronize Play (start/stop) between Roland Juno-Gi and the Drumbrute? Such that when I hit Play on the DB it triggers Play while in Recorder mode on the Juno?

The DB manual mentions Midi Machine Control (MMC) commands for Play/Stop/Rewind, but the Juno-Gi manual does not talk about these. I don't know whether these are necessary.